# HTML: Set 4 <div> as background

Tags: html, css

I've got a layout, here's my css:

```
body {
    background-color: #16193B; /* Old browsers */
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    color: white;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    overflow: hidden; 
}

html {
    min-height: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background-attachment: fixed;
}

#content {
    width: 80%;
    height: 1000px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background-color: #ADD5F7;
    overflow : hidden;
}


#wrap div{
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
}

#b1 {
    width: 80%;
    height: 1000px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background-color: #35478C;
    position:relative;
}

#b2 {
    width: 90%;
    height: 1000px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background-color: #4E7AC7;
    position:relative;
}

#b3 {
    width: 90%;
    height: 1000px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background-color: #7FB2F0;
    position:relative;
}

#b4 {
    width: 90%;
    height: 1000px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background-color: #ADD5F7;
    overflow : auto;
    position:relative;
}
```

And thats in the body of the HTML-File:

```
    <div id="b1">

        <div id="b2">
            <div id="b3">
                <div id="b4">
                    <div id="content">

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
```

This is my layout, but it should just be the background of the page... Unfortunately if I add text to some other div then "content" the rectangle overlays the others. How can I fix this? Actually I want a menu bar which is the top "layer" and overlays all under it...

Comment: Why are you using position:relative on elements that have no absolutelty-positioned children?

Comment: position:relative is just some code I added, forget about it...

Comment: @moe2801 Go to other questions you have asked and click the checkmark under the correct answer.

Comment: Ok I checked every question with an answer... I will also do it here if someone helps me.. I even would "thumb it up"...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, before you look at my jsFiddle-Solution:

1. Be aware that using divs for such backgrounds is not a beautiful solution. Best would be using a background-image on your body-tag, which you stretch with background-size. It's supported in all modern browsers. The only problem would be IE8 and downwards.
2. Your CSS is a mess. When styling elements with similar attributes, use a class instead styling every ID by itself.

I basically created a new div with your custom content and a class on your background-divs. I also had to clean up your CSS and deleted unnecessary statements:

-> **[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fymyQ/)** <-

HTML:

```
<div  class="centerIt" id="b1">
    <div  class="centerIt" id="b2">
        <div  class="centerIt" id="b3">
            <div  class="centerIt" id="b4">
                <div id="content"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="contentContainer">
    <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quisquam excepturi laboriosam illum esse voluptas libero aperiam voluptate omnis dolor odio natus tempore sunt doloribus. Suscipit iure vel totam eius reprehenderit.</div>
</div>
```

​
CSS:

```
.centerIt {
    position: relative;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;    
}
```

Comment: Wow! Thanks I will try that, if it works I'll accept it! and try to thumb it up... (and yes my CSS is a mess, I'm a total noob lol)

Comment: Yes this works, but how do I put my menu bar over all layers? So that it is in front of everything? Thanks!

Comment: Have you seen my link to jsFiddle? Look at the div with id 'contentContainer' and how it is styled in CSS.

Comment: I'm sorry I totally didn't see that! Thanks very very much! THANK YOU! Is there anything I could do beside thumbing?