# Paste background image carefully

Tags: css, html

I want to create a background image that will have no effect on other divs in my document. I have this code over here that works great:

```css
body,
html {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

#bg {
  /* The image used */
  background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  /* Full height */
  height: 100%;
  /* Center and scale the image nicely */
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}

#heading {
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: central;
  width: 40%;
  left: 30%;
  color: #F82473;
}
```

```html
<div id="heading">Some stuff</div>
<div id="bg"></div>
```

But if I switch my divs' order then it's working weird:

```css
body,
html {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

#bg {
  /* The image used */
  background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  /* Full height */
  height: 100%;
  /* Center and scale the image nicely */
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}

#heading {
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: central;
  width: 40%;
  left: 30%;
  color: #F82473;
}
```

```html
<div id="bg"></div>
<div id="heading">Some stuff</div>
```

How should I paste background image on my website so it won't affect any other divs in my document?

Comment: What do you mean by “affecting other divs” to begin with? And why are you not simply giving the background image to the html or body element, why are you introducing additional elements that then need to be positioned first?

Comment: Because I am also using canvas, so I need div to easily hide background when I need.

Comment: Well then apply it by a class, and remove that class to “hide” it …?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Kindly use div into div as you have 2 divs. one is for background and other one for Heading
it will be like

```
<div class="bg"> 
  <div id="heading">Some stuff</div> 
// All the staff for background will goes here 

 </div>
```

it will work in your case and if you use other divs after this they will not have the background image.

Answer (score 1):

Please first search before ask question

[Use a DIV as a background for another element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25970787/use-a-div-as-a-background-for-another-element)

```css
#wrapper{
    position: relative;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
}

.content{
    color: #FFFFFF;
    font-size: 26px;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-shadow: -1px -1px 1px #000, 1px 1px 1px #000;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 100;
}

.background{
    color: #999999;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: -100;
}
```