# Lazy load for background images

Tags: javascript, background-image, lazy-loading

I am trying to lazyload a background image. In order to do this I added the lazy load plugin of jquery: jquery-lazy. We install it with `npm i jquery-lazy`.

In order to have lazyloaded images I just need to add the class lazy like below:

`<img data-src="image.png" class="lazy">` with the js below:

```
<script>
  $(function($) {
    $("img.lazy").Lazy();
});
</script>
```

And it is working correctly.

Unfortunately, I don't know how to do for background images like that:

```
<div style="background-image: url(background.jpg)">
```

Indeed here the background image is added in a `<div>` in the style field...

I am wondering if I can lazyload a background image the same way I did with basic images like `<img>`.
I tried to do it by adding `<div class="lazy">` but it is not working.

Comment: Interesting question, so I did a little lookup for "div as a background for another div" (wondering if there was a way to set a div with something like your "lazy" class as the background) and I found this, it might not be "the answer" but it may point you in the right direction: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25970787/use-a-div-as-a-background-for-another-element

Comment: What's your clientele? This code seems a bit dated. Do you really need to support browsers down to IE8?

Comment: I edited my question!

Answer (score 0):

You can use jquery-lazy for any html tags:

```
<div class="lazy" style="display: block; background-image: url('http://jquery.eisbehr.de/lazy/images/3.jpg?t=1585165700');"></div>

$(function() {
    $('.lazy').lazy();
});
```

See example on site (example has wrong html tab, but you can see source on page): http://jquery.eisbehr.de/lazy/example_load-background-images

Comment: I want to lazy load my image in order to increase the performance of my website. In order to measure this performance I am using the Audit feature next to Console when you inspect a web-page. I did what you advised me to do but my background image is still not lazy-loaded. Indeed, the audit keeps advising me to lazy load this background image...

Answer (score 0):

```js
jQuery(function(){
    jQuery('.lazy').lazy({
        scrollDirection: 'vertical',
        effect: 'fadeIn',
        visibleOnly: true,
        //-------------------------------------------------
        bgLoader: function(element) {
            var small_bg = jQuery(element).css('background-image').match( /^url\(\"(.*?)\"\)$/i )[1];
            setTimeout(function() {
                var large_bg = small_bg.replace('40/80', '200/400');
                jQuery(element).css('background-image', 'url('+large_bg+')');
                jQuery(element).addClass('loaded');
                //element.load();
            }, 500);
        },
        //-------------------------------------------------
    });
});
```

```css
.lazy{
    height: 200px;
    width: 250px;    
    filter: blur(4px);
    transition: filter 2s ease-in;

    background-color: #ccc;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;

    color: #fff;
    font-size: 3rem;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}    
.lazy.loaded{
  filter: none;
}
.lazy.bg1{background-image: url(https://picsum.photos/id/1/40/80);}
.lazy.bg2{background-image: url(https://picsum.photos/id/2/40/80);}
.lazy.bg3{background-image: url(https://picsum.photos/id/3/40/80);}
.lazy.bg4{background-image: url(https://picsum.photos/id/4/40/80);}
.lazy.bg5{background-image: url(https://picsum.photos/id/5/40/80);}
.lazy.bg6{background-image: url(https://picsum.photos/id/6/40/80);}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.lazy/1.7.9/jquery.lazy.min.js"></script>


<div class="lazy bg1" data-loader="bgLoader"> 1 </div>
<div class="lazy bg2" data-loader="bgLoader"> 2 </div>
<div class="lazy bg3" data-loader="bgLoader"> 3 </div>
<div class="lazy bg4" data-loader="bgLoader"> 4 </div>
<div class="lazy bg5" data-loader="bgLoader"> 5 </div>
<div class="lazy bg6" data-loader="bgLoader"> 6 </div>
```